# How can I remove easily vector leftovers within dissolved polygons?

Tags: qgis, dissolve

I got an official government shapefile with zip code areas. After I dissolved the zip codes to the desired aggregated polygons, there are partial vector leftovers within the polygons. How can I clean them up systematically?

Below the before and after.

Before:
[image]

And here the dissolved map:
[image]

My version of QGIS is 2.18.1 with GRASS.

Comment: Are those new features themselves? or are they gaps?

Comment: You dissolved using attribute field ?

Comment: I think it can be solved with tool v.clean, and choose the option "snap"

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot for all your feedback. As far as I can see, these features are former lines. And yes, I am dissolving using attribute fields. Snap would not do the trick either. Eventually I figured it out myself (little bit proud :)). I used the vclean tool with remove area (the last option in the list as far as I remember) with a threshold of 1000 (which equals 1 km I guess). Many thanks for all your responses and have great holidays! Benjamin

Answer (score 2):

The 'Check Geometries' plugin is really helpful to fix many kinds of geometry errors:

[image]

[image]

[image]